# Stripe iOS integration get payment transaction id

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe with iOS and the payments are working with the test cards, however, I cannot find a way to get payment transaction id so that I can store the transaction id on my server for future reference.

I looked into `STPPaymentResult` and `STPPaymentContext` but couldn't find anything.

So is there a way I can get the transaction id after the payment has been charged using Stripe in iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

I found that `STPPaymentResult` returned during `didCreatePaymentResult` does contain transaction id. You can get it by `paymentResult.source.stripeID`